# tx_news direct link to news entry

Tags: typo3, tx-news

it is possible to have a direct path to a special news entry?
example:
my link is: `http://www.domain.de/start/topnewsdetail/news/really-long-name-of-news-entry.html`
and it would be nice to have
`http://www.domain.de/newsEntry.html`.

Can someone give a hint?

Comment: Is there some way to identify that the links like this `http://www.domain.de/newsEntry.html` is a link to a news? Like is there a special pattern that is never used for normal pages?

Answer (score 1):

it is a little bit complicated if you want a general automatic solution.

you can do it by hand if you insert pages of type 'external url' where you insert the long path as external url.

with realurl you have problems as realurl at least will use one path segment for the page with the detail view before the last segment which is for identifying the news record. AFAIK coolurl can ommit the path segemnt for the page.

on the other hand: make sure the news identification (title, subtitle?) is unique and does not collide with pathes for normal pages.

at last you can use .htaccess rewrites, but that needs to differentiate between short urls for news and short urls for top-level pages. So those urls will show the page, those urls are not generated inside of TYPO3 and so nowhere used (except manual)

Comment: hm, i thought about htaccess.
i think this is would be the best solution
but so i have to do this for every news entry.

Comment: you possibly can use wildcards, if your 'static' pages have only a few defined names. first catch these names/pathes and redirect to /index.php (as usual) and the remaining calls redirect to the news detail page.

Answer (score 0):

this EXT. adds a custom link to records like system category or news:
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/recordlink

It'S deployed for TYPO3 6.2 but perhabs it'S helpful to create an own EXT.?

Comment: can you better explain why?
i only find this "record" tab in rte link wizard.